# Why to use ESAPI.validator().getValidFileContent() ? What is an invalid or corrupt file?

Tags: java, xss, esapi

Please tell me.
I am using ESAPI for validation, escaping n all that and i have this confusion.
Please share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use its default validator `org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator` class for validation. Also see [this API](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.java?r=364&spec=svn364)

Comment: Do I need to validate or do output encoding/escaping with a file needed to be written in response to nullify a possible xss attack? The file is retrieved from database in byte format.  N Thanks the answer was of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ESAPI validation in two enterprise web apps.  Study the docs at the OWASP ESAPI site, but the site is very disorganized, incomplete, and often has broken links.

Update: Note that, when ESAPI.properties is not loaded, org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator handles ESAPI.validator().getValidInput().  Thus, since your custom regex in ESAPI.properties are not loaded, your validation results will vary from what was expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have already Implemented ESAPI Successfully.